# Optional Parameters in Web Api Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I want to handle POST of the following API-Call:

`/v1/location/deviceid/appid`

Additional Parameter are coming from the Post-Body.

This all works fine for me. Now I wnat to extend my code by allowing "deviceid" and/or "appid" and/or BodyData to be null:

```
/v1/location/deviceid
/v1/location/appid
/v1/location/
```

These 3 URLs should responded by the same route.

My first approach (BodyData required):

```
[Route("v1/location/{deviceid}/{appid}", Name = "AddNewLocation")]
public location_fromuser Post(string deviceid = null, string appid = null, [FromBody] location_fromuser BodyData)
{
    return repository.AddNewLocation(deviceid, appid, BodyData);
}
```

This does not work and returns a compile error:

> "optional Parameters must be at the end"

Next try:

```
[Route("v1/location/{deviceid}/{appid}", Name = "AddNewLocation")]
public location_fromuser Post([FromBody] location_fromuser BodyData, string deviceid = null, string appid = null)
```

Now my function AddNewLocation() get always an `BodyData=null` - even if the call send the Body.

Finally I set all 3 Parameter optional:

```
[Route("v1/location/{deviceid}/{appid}", Name = "AddNewLocation")]
public location_fromuser Post(string deviceid = null, string appid = null, [FromBody location_fromuser BodyData = null)
```

Don´t work:

> Optional parameter `BodyData` is not supported by `FormatterParameterBinding`.

Why do I want a solution with optional Parameters? My Controller handles just the "adding of a new Location" via a POST.

I want to send on wrong data my own exceptions or error messages. Even if the call has missing values. In this case I want to be able to decide to throw an exception or Setting Defaults by my code.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

For an incoming request like `/v1/location/1234`, as you can imagine it would be difficult for Web API to automatically figure out if the value of the segment corresponding to '1234' is related to `appid` and not to `deviceid`.

I think you should change your route template to be like
`[Route("v1/location/{deviceOrAppid?}", Name = "AddNewLocation")]` and then parse the `deiveOrAppid` to figure out the type of id.

Also you need to make the segments in the route template itself optional otherwise the segments are considered as required. Note the `?` character in this case.
For example:
`[Route("v1/location/{deviceOrAppid?}", Name = "AddNewLocation")]`

Comment: `?` inside the route template is what I was looking for.  +1

Comment: I wouldn't say that "deviceOrAppId" is the best design choice. I think the API should always know by definition what it will be receiving if at all possible.

Comment: Just for information - When we mark a parameter as optional in the action uri using `?` character then we must provide default values to the parameters in the method signature e.g. MyMethod(string name = "someDefaultValue", int? Id = null).

Comment: @RBT you da real MVP, I got stumped there for a minute. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Glad that it helped you @s.m. I've converted my comment into an answer for better visibility as it seems helpful. It will be an add-on to Kiran's post.

Answer (score 53):

Another info: If you want use a **Route Constraint**, imagine that you want force that parameter has **int** datatype, then you need use this syntax:

```
[Route("v1/location/**{deviceOrAppid:int?}**", Name = "AddNewLocation")]
```

The **?** character is put always before the last **}** character

For more information see: [Optional URI Parameters and Default Values](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional)

Answer (score 27):

An additional fact to complement @Kiran Chala's answer -

When we mark any parameter (`appid`) as optional in the action URI using `?` character(for [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)) then we must provide default value to the parameter in the method signature as shown below:

```
[Route("v1/location/{deviceid}/{appid}", Name = "AddNewLocation")]
public location_fromuser Post(string deviceid, int? appid = null)
```

Comment: I was about to comment the same.

Comment: Exactly my problem. I remembered the question mark in the route but forgot the default value in the method parameter.

Comment: why are the parameter names not matching the route token names?

Comment: Very keen observation @Choco. I've fixed the parameter names and the related portions of the answer. Thank you for your kind feedback.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I fallen here with my internet research and I continue my way, because the accepted solution not working with dotnet core 3.1.
So here is my solution, following [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{name}")]
[Route("{name}/parent/{parentId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostSomething(string name, Guid? parentId = null)
{
    return Ok(await Task.FromResult(new List<string>()));
}
```

By this way many routes go to this single API function

Comment: I thought you were on to something but for me this is generating two endpoints in swagger and both are still required. :/

Comment: Ok. maybe its swagger. I now have just [HttpPost("~/Path/Action/{paramName?}")] and a nullable int in my method, WITHOUT a default value and from postman it works fine. Swagger has just been marking all of my attempts as required this whole time. Now how to fix swagger?

Comment: @johnw182 if you want the parameter as not required you need to set a default value, bacause if you don't swagger want you to give the value but with a default it's ok.

Comment: And for the two generated endpoints it's normal, you set two routes so two endpoints are available :)

Comment: I did the default. Swagger still marked it as required and would not let it submit without a value

Comment: seems like swagger is brok

Comment: No it's totally logic, first route no need of `parentId`, second route swagger set it as required. The default value setting is for the case where you came from the first route. Be careful to not confuse between c# and swagger, swagger only describe your API's route